# Selecting data from 100 tables in AWS Glue/PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, pyspark

I have a catalog of 100 tables in the AWS Glue catalog of the format:

```
user_1
user_2
...
user_100
```

Each table has this format:

```
| id | user_id | date     | expense |
|----|---------|----------|---------|
| 1  | 1       | 20200521 | 200     |
| 2  | 2       | 20200601 | 100     |
| 3  | 1       | 20200603 | 90      |
```

Every table has the same schema where one column is expense (int type).
Each users rows get randomly inserted in to one these 100 tables.

What I want do is to check the sum of the expense column of each of the tables for a given user.

What is the most efficient way of doing this rather than creating 100 Dynamic frames and joining them. I suppose I need to create 100 datasources for each table, but is there an easier way to select the rows for a given user from all 100 tables and get the sum?

Thank you.

Comment: create a `view` out of all these tables(union all user_1...100) and query at once. syntax- https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-view.html

Comment: Thank you Kale. I will go with making a view in Redshift as my data sources are in Redshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using glue catalog, so the data must be lying in s3.
So you can create a list of all the tables path on s3 and read them as one df. This way you can also apply pushdown conditions.

```
Path = [path1, path2 .....path100]
Df = spark.read.csv(*path)

Df.groupby('user_id').agg(sum(expense)).show()
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually the data are coming from Redshift tables. Is it possible to do something similar with the table names in the catalog?

Comment: You can create a view in redshift over those 100 tables. Redshift now supports materialized views too which will get updated automatically. Then using the redshift connection directly read data from that view.

Comment: Thank you Jain. Making a materialized view in Redshift sounds like the most efficient way to do it. Cheers!